# Question about verbs in Old Japanese

Tags: etymology, conjugations, classical-japanese, old-japanese

Does anybody with in-depth knowledge of Old Japanese know why vowel-based verbal stems could only end in -e or -i (leading to the える/いる or type 2 class of verbs in Modern Japanese)? Why are there no cases of vowel based verbal stems ending in e.g. -a, -o or -u?

It is a very peculiar feature when compared to other languages that have conjugations based on the last letter/vowel of the verbal stem (such as Latin, Greek and Sanskrit)… Unfortunately my Japanese is rather rudimentary and my Old Japanese practically non-existent…

Comment: What do you mean by "vowel-based verbal stems"? And type 2 class of verbs?

Comment: @BretonLoïc The former means exactly what it says: verbs (or "verbals") whose stems end in vowels.  In Modern Japanese, an example would be *taberu*, whose stem is *tabe-*.  Compare consonant-stem verbs like *yomu*, whose stem is *yom-*.  The "type 2" terminology is just another way to refer to the class of vowel-stem verbs.

Comment: Okay then, that's not really relevant to the question but all "vowel-ending verbal stems" didn't end up being "eru/iru" verbs in modern japanese: https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%91%E3%81%B5 ゑ・ふ which became よう (酔う)

Comment: Like I said in the question, my Japanese is rather rudimentary and my Old Japanese practically inexistent, so I cannot really deliver an opinion on this… but… the wiktionary gives the etymology of 酔う as 
/wepu/ → /weɸu/ → /e.u/ → /yo.u/

This means this verb was originally a consonant-stem verb, as it ended in p, or later ɸ, although it might have functioned as a vowel-stem verb in an intermediary period...

Answer (score 3):

The capitalized *Old Japanese* (上代日本語) certainly has two vowel-stem types of verbs that yield today's *-eru/-iru* verbs respectively. However, it's not accurate to say they end in *-e/-i* because the language in the Old Japanese stage had 8 distinct "vowels", or to recent understanding, more like "rhymes":

> *a, i<sub>1</sub>, i<sub>2</sub>, u, e<sub>1</sub>, e<sub>2</sub>, o<sub>1</sub>, o<sub>2</sub>*

which merged into the current 5-vowel system by the 9th century (then it becomes called [Early Middle Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Middle_Japanese)).

The two stem-final vowels you mentioned are actually *-e<sub>2</sub>* and *-i<sub>2</sub>*, both of which were formed by contraction of adjacent vowels which are thought to have existed in earlier, pre-document ages. Since I don't have access to books such as Frellesvig (2010) now, just let me quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Japanese) for an overview:

> - *i*<sub>2</sub> < *ui: *kami*<sub>2</sub>/*kamu*- 'god, spirit', *mi*<sub>2</sub>/*mu*- 'eye', *nagi*<sub>2</sub>/*nagu*- 'a calm'.
> - *i*<sub>2</sub> < *əi: *ki*<sub>2</sub>/*ko*<sub>2</sub>- 'tree', *yomi*<sub>2</sub>/*yomo*<sub>2</sub>- 'Hades'.
> - *e*<sub>2</sub> < *ai: *me*<sub>2</sub>/*ma*- 'eye', *ame*<sub>2</sub>/*ama*- 'heaven', *ame*<sub>2</sub>/*ama*- 'rain', *kage*<sub>2</sub>/*kaga*- 'shade'.

Thus you can presume that some vowel-stem verbs were actually composed by underlying bases that end in other vowels, and suffixing **i*.

> *aka* "red, bright" / *ake<sub>2</sub>-* "brighten"
>   *oko<sub>2</sub>-s-* "raise up" / *oki<sub>2</sub>-* "arise"

Comment: This is an important point to make (+1), but I don't think you actually answer the question — why do vowel-stem verbs only end in *-e* or *-i* (or, after your explanation in *-e₂* or *-i₂*)?

Comment: @Earthliŋ Um... yes, you have a point :)

Comment: What about the hypothesis that shimo-nidan verbs all come from eru? (Or am I getting things mixed up?)

Comment: @Sjiveru I think I've heard such thing on the discussion on the development of 可能動詞 (書く > 書ける), though.

Comment: @broccoliforest There's that, too, but I seem to remember something about shimo-nidan verbs in general. (IIRC akeru is ichidan. I might be wrong, though.)

Comment: @Sjiveru It's now ichidan, but derives from nidan. We only have a slightly more than handful of old ichidan verbs.